# PL/SQL Source (Line Number) in query on v$sql / v$sqlarea table

Tags: sql, oracle

I use Oracle Enterprise Manager to monitor current load on my DB. If there is a high-load SQL I can see its details, there is also "statistics" tab. In "general" section I can see:

```
Module: JDBC Thin Client
Action: (empty)
Parsing schema: SCHEMA1
PL/SQL Source (Line Number): SCHEMA1.PACKAGE_ABC (1457)
SQL Profile: n/a
SQL Plan Baseline n/a
```

Also, I have a simple query that I can run on my database to see generally what is going on:

```
SELECT 
  q.sql_id,
  q.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
  q.ADDRESS,
  q.SQL_TEXT,
  q.last_active_time
FROM v$sqlarea q
WHERE q.last_active_time > sysdate - 1
ORDER BY last_active_time DESC
```

Question is: is there ANY way to add to the result of my query column PL/SQL Source (Line Number) which will present the same info as the Oracle Enterprise Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information from v$session. My preferred approach would be to instrument your pl/sql code with calls like:

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_action('Doing XXX in YYY);
```

When you want to know where you are. This can then be found in v$session.action

Also see the following columns which may be of interest:

```
PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID
PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID
PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
```

You can read more here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3016.htm